# find whole json element using regex

Tags: regex

I have a json below

> {"name":"abc","config":{"key":1,"value":"one","detail":{"message":
>   "testing"}}}

I need to get the whole config element that is **`"config":{"key":1,"value":"one","detail":{"message": "testing"}}`** using regex , i dont want to use any json parser, the config can contains any number of nested elements

I tried to use regex pattern - **`"config":{.*}`** but it is fetching till last } as it is greedy

any help is much appreciated

Comment: What language are you using? You'll want to set the non-greedy flag and then should capture appropriately

Comment: I  am using java

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/bX1S5k/1/

Comment: Try `"config":{[^}]+}`. You might have to escape the } in the character class depending on regex engine.

Comment: @CodeManiac it is working like charm , thanks a lot , if you want you can Reply it i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
"config":[\s\S]+?}(?=[,}])}
```

Here `[\s\S]+?` will match (lazy mode) everything followed by `} or ,`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX1S5k/6/)

Comment: This is better than the other proposed solutions right now, as it still works if you have additional deeper nesting. **However**, if there are properties after the config object those will get matched as well. If this edge case is relevant, this solution would **not work**.

Comment: @SørenD.Ptæus is this what you wanted to https://regex101.com/r/bX1S5k/4/

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes, exactly. It's a bit more general that way. +1

Comment: @CodeManiac, could you please help me,  This Regex is not working for below three jsons 
1. {"name":"abc","config":{"key":1,"value":{"one":1},"detail":"detail Message"}}        
2. {"name":"abc","config":{"key":1,"value":"one","detail":{"message": "testing"},"detail1":{"message": "testing"},"deatil2":"detail2"}, "config2": {"key": "vlaue"} }       
3. {"name":"abc","config":{"key":1,"value":"one","detail":{"message": "testing"},"details1":{ "rules": [{"rule": "aggregate"}]},"details2": [{"order": 0,"file": "file1"}]},
"config2": {"key": "vlaue"}
}

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I was able to get a working solution, however it take two regexes to complete.

First step, grab everything after `"config"`. Use capture group 1's contents:

```
"config":({.*})
```

[Demo of Regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/nzNirZ/2)

Second step, use recursive regex to match balanced constructs, checkout more on this [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) in the "balanced constructs section". It uses recursion to find the closing curly brace that corresponds to the opening curly brace after `"config":`. Use match 1's contents:

```
{(?>[^{}]|(?R))*}
```

[Demo of Regex 2](https://regex101.com/r/lF0fI1/351)

Comment: @shalaj-shukla did you take a look at my updated answer? It works with all the examples you've shared.

Comment: It's working for me. check if you have an extra trailing space in there.  https://regex101.com/r/nzNirZ/1 @shalaj-shukla

Comment: deleted my comment , by mistake i added some spaces at the end +1 , Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Could you update my answer to be the correct one?

Comment: could you please check this {"key":1,"config":{"id1":1,"Details":[{"id":1,"name":"name","dataType":"str","standard":{"set":{"dataset":["dd"],"columns":["col1","col2"]},"message":{"rules":[{"rule":"rule1","percent":100,"amtType":1},{"rule":"aggregate","percent":100,"amtType":1}]},"restatement":{"rules":["rule1","rule2"]}}}],"storages":{"dim":{"rootUrl":"url","accountKey":"key"},"fact":{"rootUrl":"url","accountKey":"key"}}},"Details1":{"name":"value","name1":"value1"},"state":"Ready","Details2":[{"key":1,"value":"one"}]} , it is fetching more than expected

Comment: Any reason you're using a regex vs. a json parser to get you config object?

Comment: all json are dynamic and i cant create model for all , using json parser it is straight forward only thing that we have to fetch is the config object from json but it could be anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186673/discussion-between-jmoney-and-shalaj-shukla).